# Why is this answer not blanked out?

Tags: discussion

After being flagged as offensive, [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22468/did-jews-take-over-73-of-their-land-from-palestinians/23384#23384) has been deleted, but the contents have not been blanked out:

> The following link perfectly explains how the supposed state of Israel
>   has plundered land that does not belong to them:
>   http://whatreallyhappened.com/WRHARTICLES/mapstellstory.html

Content that's spam or hate speech is blanked out. Does this mean that mods don't regard this content as hate speech?

Comment: Can you explain why you think that's hate speech? "In law, hate speech is any speech, gesture or conduct, writing, or display which is forbidden because it may incite violence or prejudicial action against or by a protected individual or group, or because it disparages or intimidates a protected individual or group." This is is criticism of a country, not of *a* Jew or *Jews*. The linked site even states: "Jews and arabs do NOT have a thousand year history of animosity!"

Comment: @sklivvz are Saudi Arabia, Iran or North Korea described as "supposed" countries or states? No? Then what does it imply when Israel is described as a "supposed" state?

Comment: What does it imply? That the OP comes from a country where Israel is not recognized? There are [30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_recognition_of_Israel) of them.

Comment: I'm scratching my head by the epimenidean nature of this meta-question. If it is a fair criticism, do I need to blank this question out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't involved in the handling of the original flag, so this answer may be less than satisfactory.

> the contents have not been blanked out

Just to be clear to the users with less rep points: once you get to 10,000 rep, you can see posts that are deleted. (I think it is also visible through the Data Explorer). This is a good thing (IMO) because it allows trusted users to vet the work of the moderators.

However, it leads to some weird situations:

- If we delete a post because it is spam, and it can still be seen by a lot of people, have the spammers won? (At least Google doesn't see it.)
- If we delete a post because it is is libellous/hateful/doxxing/copyright-infringing/plagiarism etc., and it can still be seen by a lot of people, have we really respected the victims?

We can edit away the contents, which means it is only visible in the edit history - i.e. not to casual inspection, but available for more deliberate effort.

In some cases, it is possible to take it a step further and destroy the contents more thoroughly, but it is a rather severe action (and <strike>may sometimes require</strike> always requires developer support).

> Content that's spam or hate speech is blanked out.

Is that a hard and fast rule? I'm not sure it is. For example, if enough users simply use the "flag as spam" option, the system deletes it, but doesn't blank it. (I bet there are fancy spam-detecting rules, but I don't know what they are.)

Should it be a rule??

> Does this mean that mods don't regard this content as hate speech?

I personally don't, but I don't think that means very much at all. It is an opinion, probably based largely on my ignorance and my privilege, and very little thought. It is also based on my general policy of preferring to err on the side of non-censorship.

If that is a mistaken opinion, let's fix it. I don't have an infallible opinion.